# Data are inserted while fields are empty

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the following code to insert data in MySQL:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {
$insertSQL=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (ID, COUNTRY, POSTAL_CODE, ADDRESS, PHONE, FAX) VALUES (:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f)");
    $insertSQL->bindValue(':a', $_POST['ID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insertSQL->bindValue(':b', $_POST['COUNTRY'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertSQL->bindValue(':c', $_POST['POSTAL_CODE'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insertSQL->bindValue(':d', $_POST['ADDRESS'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertSQL->bindValue(':e', $_POST['PHONE'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insertSQL->bindValue(':f', $_POST['FAX'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insertSQL->execute();
}
```

the problem is that when I don't enter values in both text fields PHONE and ADDRESS, they are set to 0 in my database instead of NULL!!
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you don't fill anything in the fields, you receive an empty string. This is not the same as `NULL` and will cause PDO to convert it to the given type `PDO::PARAM_INT`

To insert `NULL`, you must pass `NULL` to PDO:

```
$insertSQL->bindValue(
    ':d', 
    $_POST['PHONE'] ?: NULL, 
    PDO::PARAM_INT
);
```

Comment: Nothing says "this works perfectly" more than [an accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/about).